# Scroll pane isn't coming down when add components

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have this simple program where I upload images into a java db database (just add their location to the data base as well as their type) then I show them in the program in a scrollpane the problem is the scrollpane isn't scrolling down,

this is my code

```
    `        
    JPanel cont = new JPanel();
    cont.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());
    cont.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    while(sports_re.next()){

        String location=sports_re.getString("LOCATIONN");
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
        JLabel picLabe = new JLabel();
        picLabe.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new 
        ImageIcon(location).getImage().getScaledInstance(100, 100, 
        Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        cont.add(picLabe);

    }      
    }
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().setView(cont);
            `
```

I tried to add width and height to  the dimension  and it worked but I have to put a huge number for it to work (if I put a small number it won't allow me to scroll ) [It's not right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Unw.png)

[this is what it looks like without the "cont.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yz2oJ.png)
  I want to make it dynamic, please help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
cont.setPreferredSize(new Dimension());
```

Remove this to let LayoutManager calculate the size. TGhen scrollpane reflect the calculated size rather than fixed you provided.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work, It puts everything in one line